# If a company never invoices me, am I obligated to do anything?

Tags: canada, british-columbia, payment, invoice

I hired a driving school to help me get my driver's license. My test was cancelled due to COVID and my last lesson was about a week before the test. The driving school and testing facility are two entirely separate entities but both closed down due to COVID.

How or when payment was to be made was never discussed with the driving school. They haven't contacted me despite my last lesson being over a month ago. I had tried discussing it with the teacher but he sort of deflected the questions saying collecting pay wasn't really his department.

I found the teacher did a bad job and I lost my job due to COVID. If they don't ask me to pay should I take any action? Is their a time limit they have to ask or I have to pay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### "One day and that day may never come"

> If a company never invoices me, am I obligated to do anything?

No (given that they know how to contact you i.e. you are not evading being invoiced).

That said, you will still owe the money. When/if they ask it to be paid, you will need to pay.

But there is no need to proactively bug them to take the payment. Until invoiced, you can enjoy the money as a zero-interest loan.

Comment: I'm guessing that the utility in his having taken the course was to fulfill his need for a drivers license. If the company did not or could not fulfill that need, I would contend that the contract was not satisfied on their end - and therefore is void - and would negate the need for payment, or at least a partial payment.

Comment: @markb The "utility" is not necessarily the contract deliverable. Universities charge you regardless of you getting job after studies. Gyms charge you regardless of you losing weight. Beauty saloons charge you regardless of you getting a good date afterwards etc. etc.